# Can wireless ceiling fan controls work without a direct wire to a wall switch?

Tags: electrical

Is there a wireless controller that can control fan without the direct wire from switch to fan?  There is direct power at fan, and direct power at switch but they are not connected together.  Looking for a way to control fan without running wire to fan.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of retro fit kits to make pull chain fans wireless.  Just search for Ceiling Fan Remote Control Kit.  Most big box hardware stores have them in stock as well.  The wall switch will not be used but you can mount the remote on the wall next to the switch.

Answer (score 0):

Ceiling fan remote control modules do not require a switch, they only require power. On the input side they'll have a black ungrounded "hot" lead, a white grounded "neutral" lead, and a green/bare grounding lead.  The ungrounded "hot" lead can be connected to either a switched conductor, or a conductor that comes directly from the panel unswitched.